# How to mount a VeraCrypt container on a RPi with optimal performance?

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem, storage, encryption

On a Raspberry Pi, in order to use a VeraCrypt encrypted container/partition, **which solution offers the best performance between installing VeraCrypt or using `cryptsetup` ([that seems to support it](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TrueCrypt#Accessing_a_TrueCrypt_or_VeraCrypt_container_using_cryptsetup))?**

---

Context: I have an USB3 external HDD, that will contain:

- a VeryCrypt 1 TB container, hosted inside an exFAT (1) or NTFS partition (2), to be able to read the HDD with Windows in the future if needed
- or a Veracypt 1 TB *partition* (3)

I'll benchmark (1), (2), (3) to see which one offers the highest read/write performance from RPi.

Answer (score 2):

I've run a big number of tests today on a RaspberryPi4 2GB (with official PSU, and checked that no throttling happened; standard RaspiOS).

I used an external USB3 HDD, tested to be able to both read and write from the RPi4 *faster than 70 MB/s* for sequential 1 GB file, when using a normal (unencrypted) `ext4` partition (just to be sure the disk itself is not the weakest element in the chain).

The following results are to be taken in *relative* value to compare the FS, not in absolute value.

I tested both:

- the RAW write speed on an encrypted partition

  ```
  dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/b/1000mb bs=1M count=1000 iflag=fullblock
  ```

  (even if constant zero bytes, AES algorithm has to re-encrypt each block, in order for the repetition not be identifiable, see crypto.SE for questions about this, it's common)
- the speed of transfer with Samba when sending a 2.3 GB file from a Windows computer to the RPi encrypted partition/container (again I checked that networking, destination computer's disk, etc. were not a bottleneck)

As I want the disk containing encrypted data to be also openable on Windows (let's say my wife needs it), without Linux command-line commands, **I tested only exFAT and NTFS**.

### Results

```
host ↓       FS inside container →   exFAT                       NTFS
Veracrypt part.                      dd:41 MB/s  samba:!! MB/s   dd:28 MB/s  samba: 25 MB/s
exFAT part. + Veracrypt container    dd:39 MB/s  samba:!! MB/s   dd:25 MB/s  samba: 20 MB/s
NTFS part. + Veracrypt container     dd:29 MB/s  samba:!! MB/s   dd:25 MB/s  samba: 15 MB/s
```

`!!`: unresponsive Windows Explorer at the beginning of the transfer of 2.3 GB file, for about ~ 30 seconds, and then it begins but quite slow. This seems to be a bug when using `fuse-exfat` + `samba` + `1 GB+ file tranfer` from Windows, even without using VeraCrypt. It is even amplified when there is an additional Veracrypt layer.

As a conclusion, the best option if we want the encrypted disk to be readable on Windows too, and to be able to use it via Samba, is to use a Veracrypt partition, containing a NTFS partition.

---

Note: when not using encryption, using [this little "big_writes" trick](https://forum.libreelec.tv/thread/21809-slow-usb3-ntfs-smb-write-speeds/) helps to speed up NTFS writes from 30 MB/s to more than 70 MB/s:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda4 /mnt/a -o big_writes
```

But again, after the additional Veracrypt layer, we fall again to ~ 20-30 MB/s.